# Access denied when copying BigQuery tables between GCP projects

Tags: google-bigquery

I have projects P1,P2 in europe-west2. In both projects I have same dataset/table structure at same location europe-west2.
In P1, I created a service account and added the same service account (SA) to P2, like here:
https://gtseres.medium.com/using-service-accounts-across-projects-in-gcp-cf9473fef8f0

In both projects, the SA has role BigQuery Admin.

I want to copy a table from P1 to P2. I do

```
bq --project_id P1 --service_account_credential_file <path to SA json> cp P1:dataset.table P2:dataset.table
```

The script seems to find the tables and asks

> cp: replace P2:dataset.table? (y/n)

After confirming, cp says:

> BigQuery error in cp operation: Access Denied: Project P1: User does
> not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project P1.

If I try to copy in the other direction then I get:

> BigQuery error in cp operation: Access Denied: Permission bigquery.tables.get denied on table
> P1:dataset.sessions (or it may not exist).

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be about permissions. You need these permissions:

**On the source dataset:**

- bigquery.tables.get
- bigquery.tables.getData

**On the destination dataset:**

- bigquery.tables.create.

**Permission to run a copy job:**

- bigquery.jobs.create IAM permission.
- bigquery.datasets.create permission

Also,  you need these IAM roles that include the permissions you need to run a copy job:

- roles/bigquery.user
- roles/bigquery.jobUser
- roles/bigquery.admin

You can use this command to copy tables:

```
bq --location=location cp \
-a -f -n \
project_id:dataset.source_table \
project_id:dataset.destination_table
```

You can read this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copy-table).